# How to move Locally developed Prestashop to hosting server

Tags: prestashop-1.7

I have installed `Prestashop 1.7` with `MariaDB`, in local system it is working fine. I have developed 4 different pages. I want to move this pages to hosting server? Do i need to install the same `Prestashop` version in the hosting server or just copy and paste will work?. I developed in Ubuntu 16.04 system. Do i need do some changes in db developed in local system while moving to hosting server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After all setting Also You need to Change in ps_configuration table of DB.
In the name column, find the **PS_SHOP_DOMAIN** and **PS_SHOP_DOMAIN_SSL** row In the value column and write new domain name that you want PrestaShop to use.

Answer (score 1):

**You should simply follow this process:**

1. Transfer your files through FTP to your hosting server
2. Transfer your database through phpMyAdmin to your hosting server (make use to use utf8_general_ci as a charset)
3. Upon transfer completion, edit /config/settings.inc.php to set the right MySQL password (the one provided by your hosting provider)
4. In your PrestaShop admin-panel, configure your main shop URL as well as if you want to use SSL (recommended) or not

Voilà!